# Perl - basic STDIN issue

Tags: linux, perl, stdin

I'm now with Perl.

i have the following code which the purpose is to extract the software name
by text parsing.
the software name in this case is "ddd" :

```
print "Please provide full installation path (Ex:/a/b/c/ddd)\n";
my $installPath = <STDIN>;
#going to extract software name
my @soft     = split '/', $installPath;
my $softName = print "@soft[4]\n";
print "$softName\n";
```

but,
instead of getting "ddd" as software name i got:

```
ddd
1
```

i don't understand from where the '1' comes from?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5):

The error comes from this:

```
my $softName = print "@soft[4]\n";
#              ^^^^^
```

The function [`print`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/print.html) returns `1` (true) when it succeeds, which it does here. The `1` is assigned to your variable, which you then print.

```
print "$softName\n";
```

Short recap:

```
my $installPath = <STDIN>;               # "/a/b/c/ddd"
my @soft     = split '/', $installPath;  # 5th element is "ddd"
my $softName = print "@soft[4]\n";       # this prints "ddd", but "1" is returned
#              ^^^^^   print returns 1, which is assigned to $softName
print "$softName\n";                     # "1" is printed
```

What you want is:

```
my $softName = $soft[4];
```

Which is just taking the 5th element of the array. You should use `$` and not `@` when referring to a single element. You can use `@` when referring to a slice, multiple elements.

---

A better way to do what you are trying to do is using `File::Basename`:

```
use File::Basename;
my $softName = basename($installPath);
```

[`File::Basename`](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Basename) is a core module in Perl 5.

Comment: Thank you. but is there a way to use the 'print' but without getting the '1' ?

Comment: Like I just said in the answer, the reason you got `1` is because `print` returns `1` (true) when it succeeds. This `1` is then printed when you print the variable.

Comment: @Assafbaruch I'm not sure if you understand this or not.... if not, you should say something.

Answer (score 0):

`my $softName = print "@soft[4]\n";` is a bad way of treating an array, and this is what is causing the issue.

When referencing an array as a whole, then the `@` should be used. What you have done here by referencing `@soft[4]`, you do point at a particular value in the array, but you are still referring to it in an array context, and since `$softName` is a scalar that only wants one single value, perl tries its best to figure out what you want, since you want nothing like it at all. To make it clear to perl that you are referencing a specific item in the array and not the array as a whole, use `$` instead. Perl will understand since you also specify `[4]`.

In addition, what is being assigned to `$softName` is not that array value, but the result of the `print` which is the status code (this is where the "1" comes from).

**To correct your code, change that line to:**

```
my $softName = $soft[4];
```